# Entity framework Code first Cascade delete for table having multiple foreign keys

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I have the following POCO models and I was trying to enable cascade delete between customer and learner but getting an error which is.

> Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint
>   'FK_dbo.Customers_dbo.Companies_CompanyId' on table 'Customers' may
>   cause cycles or multiple cascade paths. Specify ON DELETE NO ACTION or
>   ON UPDATE NO ACTION, or modify other FOREIGN KEY constraints. Could
>   not create constraint. See previous errors.

**Company.cs**

```
public class Company
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Course> Courses { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Customer> Customers { get; set; }
    }
```

**Customer.cs**

```
public class Customer
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int CompanyId { get; set; }
        public virtual Company Company { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Learner> Learners { get; set; }
    }
```

**Course.cs**

```
 public class Course
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int CompanyId { get; set; }
    public virtual Company Company { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Learner> Learners { get; set; }
}
```

**Learner.cs**

```
 public class Learner
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int CustomerId { get; set; }
    public virtual Customer Customer { get; set; }
    public int CourseId { get; set; }
    public virtual Course Course { get; set; }
}
```

**Mapping Files are as follows:**

```
 public class CompanyMapping : EntityTypeConfiguration<Company>
    {
        public CompanyMapping()
        {

        }
    }

    public class CourseMapping : EntityTypeConfiguration<Course>
    {
        public CourseMapping()
        {
            HasRequired(c => c.Company)
               .WithMany(comp => comp.Courses)
                .HasForeignKey(c => c.CompanyId);
        }
    }

    public class CustomerMapping : EntityTypeConfiguration<Customer>
    {
        public CustomerMapping()
        {
            HasRequired(cust => cust.Company)
               .WithMany(comp => comp.Customers)
               .HasForeignKey(cust => cust.CompanyId);
        }
    }

    public class LearnerMapping : EntityTypeConfiguration<Learner>
    {
        public LearnerMapping()
        {
            HasRequired(l => l.Customer)
                .WithMany(c=>c.Learners)
                .WillCascadeOnDelete(true);


            HasRequired(l => l.Course)
                .WithMany(c=>c.Learners)
                .WillCascadeOnDelete(true);
        }
    }
```

**Following situations works perfectly**

- When I delete the company all of its customers, courses and learners are auto-deleted.
- When I delete the course learners are also deleted.
- When I delete the learner its also deleted easily.

**Desired Outcome**

When I try to delete a customer. It doesn't let me do it because of its learners. I want to enable cascade delete for the customer to the learner as well. How to achieve this using EF code first?

Comment: You say _I am having errors_ but you don't put the exceptions details. I downvoted => http://idownvotedbecau.se/noexceptiondetails/